# Bad handshake: Error while using request in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests

Here iam using a request module to download the api information from github and code is shown below.

```
# Creation of Github request

# Import requests
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user','pass'))
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

While using this module there is a error

```
python github.py           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "github.py", line 6, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user','pass'))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

What i have tried:

Replaced the username and password with my authentation details and it gave the following error.

```
401
application/json; charset=utf-8
utf-8
{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
{u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/v3', u'message': u'Bad credentials'}
```

Tried to work with access token in the settings tab of github but it was no use.

Any help? Please help me solve this problem.

Also requests modules is installed on my system.

Comment: is there any backslash in your password (would be bad luck!)

Comment: `certificate verify failed` indicates a self-signed or bad certificate when getting data over HTTPS (not HTTP). Either try changing your url to `http://` or fix your certificate. I just noticed you're fetching against `github.com`, do you have a proxy in between?

Comment: looks like your client can not validate server certificate

Comment: It's likely an SNI issue, can you try updating requests? `pip install -U requests[security]`

Comment: Why don't you use one of the Github API clients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user','pass'), verify=False)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

This might work, if that's the case.. Then you have trouble verifying the certificate sent from the server (seeing as you're using HTTPS).

### There's a whole [section about this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

> Requests verifies SSL certificates for HTTPS requests, just like a web browser. By default, SSL verification is enabled, and Requests will throw a SSLError if it's unable to verify the certificate:

Note that you shouldn't disable TLS/SSL verification for production code, rather investigate why the certificate isn't valid and follow the guide lines from the official documentation.

### Manual verification

You can always export the github certificate from say a browser and place the cert in the same directory as your script. Now this should normally not be needed, but as a test.. This should work:

```
r.get('https://api.github.com', verify='./github.crt')
```

And again, make sure you've exported the certificate and placed it as `github.crt` in the same directory as your script.